# Laravel route filter to specific url

Tags: php, routes, ckeditor, laravel

I'm trying to apply route filter to a specific url. So, my file is under public directory:

```
/public/js/kcfinder/browse.php
```

My filter:

```
Route::filter('admin', function ()
{

    if (!Sentry::check())
    {
        // if not logged in, redirect to login

        return Redirect::to_route('admin_login');
    }
    elseif (!Sentry::user()->has_access('is_admin'))
    {
        //logout
        Sentry::logout();
        // has no access
        return View::make('error.access_error');
    }

});
```

Finally my pattern:

```
Route::filter('pattern: js/kcfinder/*', 'admin');
```

If I try to access

```
/public/js/kcfinder/browse.php
```

the rule does not work.

I can see whole contents of file.

If I try to acess

```
/public/js/kcfinder/blahblah.php
```

the filter works great. Because there is no file which named

```
blahblah.php
```

under the directory.

Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `.htaccess` file says that if the request URI matches an existing file, then don't rewrite, just show/execute the file as it is.

So, you have two options:

You can create the necessary filters in your `.htaccess` file so that files in certain directories **always** get rewritten and sent to `index.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/js/kcfinder
RewriteRule \.php$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

This condition-and-rule set would need to be placed above the conditions that check for files and directories.

Alternatively, you can create authenticated routes in Laravel that manually fetch and execute the files. (This is not recommended as you would have to make use of `eval()`.)

Answer (score 1):

I've been down this path with trying to integrate ckfinder into Laravels auth system and ultimately found it to be too much effort. It's probably possible but my solution was simple hack. When I render the Ckeditor widget, I set a plain old session variable in PHP, then check for the existence of the session var in ckfinders auth check routine.

```
// When rendering widget
session_start();
$_SESSION['enable_ckeditor'] = true;

// In ckfinder somewhere
session_start();
return isset( $_SESSION['enable_ckeditor'] ) ?: $_SESSION['enable_ckeditor'];
```

Comment: I did fix by the similar way. Just added session start to start.php and after use eventlistener to listen all view events...